# XML Catalog in Eclipse is not working

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, code-completion, catalog

Where I work we do not have any internet connection. We still want to have validation and code completion when editing xml files. I have tried the instructions here http://www.helmers.nu/?p=276

However, I try the instructions, restarts eclipse, do reload dependencies. I still cannot get any code completion nor validation. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried both with Eclipse Galileo and Helios.

My catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <uri name="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" uri="file:///C:/dev/XMLSchemaDefinition/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

My xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">


</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your catalog, you map "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" to a local URI, yet in your XML file you say that the schema location is "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd".

Eclipse tries to resolve "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd" via XML Catalog and doesn't find an entry so on to the net it hops.

I would recommend adding another entry to your catalog that maps your public schema location URI to the same local file.